# How to bunch of record in databases using migration?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

how to save data into database when rails migration run. I have records of city and i would like to save data into databases when i create a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `db/seeds.rb` file is there so you can add seeded data to your database. You can create your records inside of there using ActiveRecord (it is just a ruby file):

```
City.create! :name => "New York", ...
```

You can populate your database with your seeds by running `rake db:seed`. You can also chain your migration/seed commands together:

```
rake db:migrate db:seed
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another migration and just add ActiveRecord statements into the migration.  Should work fine.  Are you running into any issues?